# Number of points in a grid sum of whose indexes is less then K

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Given a grid find how many points a robot can navigate given if it can explore a point where sum of digits of both X,Y(co-ordinates) is smaller than K.

One obvious solution is O(n^2).(Looping through the 2D matrix and accepting/ignoring a point based on the condition)
Other is take 0 to K-1 elements in an array , then find 2 elements such that there sum is less then K. involves O(k) space and O(k) time.

Can anyone suggest some better approach, improving upon anything in terms of space time . I am looking for a better answer.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. You want to know which points in the grid have `x+y < K`?

Comment: x,y are row,column in matrix yes i want to know how manu such points are there in the matrix whose sum of row+column is less then k

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation `x+y = K` defines a **diagonal** in your grid, from a point in the northwest to a point in the southeast.

[image: x+y=K graph]

If the points in your grid are all integral values of `x` and `y`, and `K` is an integer too, then the number of points south of the diagonal (`x+y < K`) will be `K(K-1)/2`.

The number of points in the grid including the diagonal (`x+y <= K`)  will be `K(K+1)/2`.

Obviously, this is computed in constant time `O(1)`.

Comment: Suppose my matrix is of size 3 x 4 , K =6 ,  X and y basically represents the row,column , can you now throw a liitle light on your solution

Comment: The thing is you have to split your problem into square parts and triangle parts. You can sum the number of elements in a triangle part with the equations in my answer, and the number of elements in a `m x n` square (or rectangle) part is `mn`.

Comment: In `3x4`, the line `x+y=6` touches your rectangle's bounds for `x=3, y=6/3=2` and `y=4 x=6/4=1.5`. You have to exclude the points in the upper right triangle, which are `3`. If you make drawings of the different possible cases, you will find all pertinent equations.

Comment: The formula `K(K+1)/2` is the sum of values `1+2+3+4+...+K`.

Comment: for a square with side length k area is k*k. half the area (or half the grid points) is k*k/2. but to exclude the diagonal elements of which there are k many we subtract k/2 since half the area of the square contains half the diagonal parts. k*k/2 - k/2 = K(K-1)/2
note u can change to plus to include the diagonal and similarly modify for a rectangle